# How to reduce use of await keyword in async await while maintaining execution order

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

```
async function foo() {
  await this.getAsync();
  await this.getAsyncTwo();
  await this.getAsyncThree();
  await this.getAsyncFour();
}
```

See how foo has multiple await calls, is there a way of simplyfing this while keeping execution order?

I wish it was possible to write something like

```
async function foo() {
  await 
   this.getAsync(), 
   this.getAsyncTwo(), 
   this.getAsyncThree(), 
   this.getAsyncFour();
}
```

or

```
async function foo() {
  await 
   this.getAsync() 
   .this.getAsyncTwo() 
   .this.getAsyncThree()
   .this.getAsyncFour();
}
```

Comment: I fear it's already in it's simplest form. Depending on what you plan to do with the results of those awaits, using the array method below might save you a line or two for the cost of more characters per line of code.

Comment: Can you post your actual code, please, so that we may judge based on the purpose of those calls?

Comment: The actual code contains 4 calls in one function scope (backbone js model). Async await have already made life alot easier compared to the nested .then() => {} calls..

Comment: `async/await` is part of ES2017, not ES7.

Comment: @felixKling fair enough :)

Comment: None of your functions return anything? Less isn't always more.

Comment: @jib in reality they change attribute data on an backbone model, so yeah stuff happen that I need to await for..

Comment: I mean once you return something e.g. `let result = await this.getAsync();` then your semantic optimization breaks down.

Comment: @jib sure It would break down in some cases, however in my case I am working on attributes directly on the object (an backbone model). This means in the case at hand it would not break down..

Answer (score 3):

This will guarantee the sequential execution order you wished for.

---

```
async function foo() {
  const functions = [this.getAsync, this.getAsyncTwo, ...];

  for (let func of functions) { 
    await func();
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for something simpler, not something more complex.

Comment: You need to bind this, or this will be wrong in each function.

Comment: depends who calls foo() and he hasn't done it, so I assume it's the same Object :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can await on a `Promise.all()`

```
await Promise.all([this.getAsync(), this.getAsyncTwo(), /* etc */])
```

Comment: But is get this.getAsync() executed before this.getAsyncTwo()?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve :(

Comment: I have upvoted you, seems we had similar approach as your edit being more elegant.

Comment: The second one does not work at all. Neither is the `async` callback necessary, nor does the `this` value in the method work, nor will it be evaluated sequentially, not will anything be awaited at all.

Comment: You're quite right, I had some serious misunderstandings about the way sync worked. Apologies and corrected.

Comment: So using Promise.all is execution order maintained? :/

Comment: no, it is not. for maintenance of order, see @leo 's answer.